# Insert data from a dynamically populated table into mysql database

Tags: php

Please i am stocked and don't know what to do. I am new and need help

This query Fetch data from my database school course table

```
$Mat = $_SESSION["MatriculationNo"];

$nwsq = $con->query("SELECT schoolcourse.CourseCode, CourseTittle, CourseUnit FROM schoolcourse, studentbio WHERE studentbio.MatriculationNo = '{$Mat}' AND studentbio.Department = schoolcourse.Deparment AND studentbio.Level = schoolcourse.Level");
?>
```

The code below holds the form input

```
<div class="container">
<div class="single">
<div class="form-container">
<h3 class="w3ls-title w3ls-title1">Course Registeration Form</h3>
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">

<div class="row">
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
<label class="col-md-3 control-lable" for="firstName">Surname</label>
<div class="col-md-9">
<input type="text" name="Surname" path="firstName" id="firstName" class="form-control input-sm" value="" required="" />
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
<label class="col-md-3 control-lable" for="lastName">Other Names</label>
<div class="col-md-9">
<input type="text" name="Othernames" path="lastName" id="lastName" class="form-control input-sm" value="" required="" />
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
<label class="col-md-3 control-lable" for="lastName">Matriculation Number</label>
<div class="col-md-9">
<input type="text" name="Matno" path="lastName" id="Mat" class="form-control input-sm" value="" required="" />
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

This part displays the result of the select query using while loop

```
<div class="row">
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
<div class="col-md-9">
<?php
if ($nwsq) {
echo "<table><tr><th>CourseCode</th>
<th>CourseTittle</th>
<th>CourseUnit</th>
</tr>";

// output data of each row

while($row = $nwsq->fetch_assoc()) {

echo "<tr><td>".$row["CourseCode"]."</td>
<td>" . $row["CourseTittle"]. "</td>
<td>" . $row["CourseUnit"]. "</td>
</tr>";

}

?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<input type="button" name="Create" value="RegisterCourse" />
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

How do i write an insert query to insert this data being displayed by the while loop into a table on mysql database. My code is like this

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['Create'])){

$FName = $_POST['Surname'];
$OName = $_POST['Othernames'];
$Mat = $_POST['Matno'];
//what do I do to get the td of CourseCode, CourseTittle, CourseUnit and pass them to a variable to hold each array

//My insert query is like this
//The $con variable holds mysqli connection to my db

$statmt = $con->query("INSERT INTO courseregistrationtable (Surname, Othername, MatriculationNo, CourseCode, CourseTittle, CourseUnit) Values('{$FName}', '{$OName}', '{$Mat}', '{$VariableForCourseCode}', '{$VariableForCourseTittle}', '{$VariableForCourseUnit}')");

}
?>
```

Comment: Please don't write new code with `mysql_` function, please use `mysqli_`.  When using user-supplied data in a query, you should protect against injection attacks. Are you trying to INSERT or SELECT?  The while loop is already displaying database data, why would you want to save redundant data?

Comment: You want to take data from an html table and put it in to the database? If that's not what you meant, please clarify the question.

Comment: You're pulling data out of the database and displaying it. Why do you need to put it back in the database? Your question still makes no sense.

Comment: Yes that's what i meant but the table i am getting the data from is getting is data from the while loop

Comment: @Difster the reason is that i am pulling these data from a list of stored info on my db, and i want to post all of the data displaying from the while loop to a different table on my db tag to an identy

Comment: I see. Well, just write an insert statement in your While loop so that the data you're pulling out of one table goes back in another in whatever way you want to format it, check for conditions, etc.

OR you could write all your new data to an array, then loop through the array after the while loop has completed and insert in to the other table during that loop.

Comment: @Difster Please can you write the syntax for this

Comment: @CyberOfure - I provided a code example as an answer since it's too lengthy for a comment.

Answer (score -1):

Here's how to do take the values from one table and put them in another.

```
 $temp_array = array(); //initialize array   
 while($result = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) { //your current while loop
       echo '<tr>
             <td>'.$result["forename"].'</td>
             <td>'.$result["surname"].'</td>
             </tr>';
       $temp_array[] = array('forename=>$result['forename'], 'surname'=>$result['surname']);
 }
```

Then, after the while loop, you can do this:

```
foreach($temp_array as $arr){
     foreach($arr as $key=>$val){
        if($key == "forename"){ $forename = $val; }
        if($key == "surname") { $surname = $val; }
        $sql = "INSERT INTO sometable (forename, surname) VALUES ($forename, 
                $surname)";
        //execute query as you normally would. Note, the above query is a
        //sample, you'll probably need some other identifier in there also 
        //which I'm not aware of based on your code.

     }
 }
```

Comment: please i am confused on how to go with the insert statement inside the foreach cause i am new to php please kindly give me an example thanks

Comment: please i really need this

Comment: @CyberOfureq - I added a code example, but you're going to have to adapt it to your specific needs.

Comment: i tried the code but it isn't working. I'd post a sample of my code below

Comment: I have reedited my code for best clarity of the difficulty I'm facing please check it all over please. Thanks in anticipation